# How to track URLSessionTask after Alamofire retries the request

Tags: alamofire, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

We are using Alamofire 4 and want to match `URLSessionTask`s to entities in a database.

We first used the `taskDescription` field of `URLSessionTask` to put UUID of a database entity there, but then figured out that Alamofire creates a new task on request retry and this field is not copied over. `taskIdentifier` also changes with every new task created, and there seem to be no way to track the change of `taskIdentifier` in Alamofire.

Are there any other techniques to match tasks and entities in a database or files? The end goal is to delete file + entity if background upload request succeeds. And that might happen after the app has been terminated, thus we currently store information in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming AlamoFire isn't doing something nutty, you should be able to do something like this:

```
NSString *const identifierProperty = @"com.you.yourProduct.requestID";
NSString *myIdentifier = [NSUUID UUID].UUIDString;
[NSURLProtocol setProperty:myIdentifier
                     inKey:identifierProperty
                  inRequest:theURLRequest];
```

and then, later, to get it back:

```
NSString *requestID = [NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:identifierProperty
                                          inRequest:theURLRequest];
```

Apologies for the Objective-C, but it should be easily convertible to Swift.

Once you do that, the property should be copied whenever the request is copied, just like any first-class property on the request.  You might even consider creating a category on `NSURLRequest` to expose the underlying value as an actual native property.